# UIWebView, can a button on a page trigger an app's view change?

Tags: objective-c

I load up a UIWebView in my app which displays html text and a sign out button.

Is it at all possible that when the user taps the html button it can then change the view? ie: it will go back in navigation of the app to the previous view?

Any examples of this being done?

Can this also be done in java for my Android version?

Edit: If I place an event using JS or something on the button can I then use a listener within the app's web view to go back a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is...

When one of your buttons is pressed, it actually attempts to send the user to a new URL (eg, through a href="", or javascript redirect). But, in your app's code you can use UIWebView's delegate methods to intercept the loading of the URL and instead run some app-based code.

Eg.

```
- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    NSString *_url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", request.URL];

    if ([_url rangeOfString:@"?signout"].location != NSNotFound) {
        [self userRequestsLogout];
        return NO;      
    }

    return YES;

}
```

Don't forget that UIWebView also has;

```
- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script
```

Hopefully this helps.